# AngularJS - updating directive's view after broadcasting event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, ecmascript-6

In my angular application (using ES6) I need to make an ajax call after some custom event is fired from other directive with the code below:

```
class GridController {
constructor($scope, $rootScope, MyService) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
    this.MyService = MyService

    this.MyService.getItems(arg1, arg2).then((resp) => {
                this.viewModel= resp;
            });

    this.$rootScope.$on('myEvent', (e, args) => {
        this.MyService.getItems(arg1, args[1]).then((resp) => {
                this.viewModel= resp;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that the view is not updated after the **successful** ajax call.
Is there any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: `this.MyService.getItems(arg1, args[1])` - There is no arg1. Typo?

Comment: I've removed the code, these arguments come from binded properties for current directive

Answer (score 0):

It may be model update problem try this.

```
$scope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ajax-call happens outside of angulars digest cycle. You have tried calling `$scope.$digest()`? This fires the watchers of the current scope; they should pick up the model change.

Comment: @OstapLisovyj are you sure `resp` contains the correct data and the callback really gets called? Everything looks fine.

Comment: yes, data is in the same format, since I make the same ajax as before catching the event, the difference is that I use one of the arguments from event to make the call